# How should I use neither/nor/not/or in negating expressions?

Tags: grammar

My friend and I are confused on negations. we thought it could be because of possible different use of negation in countable or uncountable nouns, but our problem definition could be wrong.
So what can we learn from this?

Which one(s) out of these below is/are the most correct, concise, and natural expression(s)?

1a. Most probably there is neither an escape from love nor faking it.
1b. Most probably there is neither escape from love nor faking it.

2a. Most probably there is not an escape from love nor faking it.
2b. Most probably there is not an escape from love or faking it.

3a. Most probably there is not escape from love or faking it.
3b. Most probably there is not escape from love nor faking it.

4a. Most probably there is no escape from love or faking it.
4b. Most probably there is no escape from love nor faking it.

Comment: What is "it"? Love or an escape?

Comment: "To escape from love" is alright, but could you explain what you mean by "escape from faking love"? Imitating it?

Comment: I d like to say there is no escape from love and also there is no faking love. how could you merge these in simplest and grammatically correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences center around the inevitability of love and the trueness of love. To describe this relationship, you can use the following constructs

> neither... nor...
>   *neither apples nor bananas*
>
> not... nor...
>   *not apples nor bananas*
>
> no... or...
>   *no apples or bananas*

Your sentences could also be reworded as

> There is no escaping love neither is there faking love.
>
> There is no escaping or faking  love.
>
> One can neither escape nor fake love.
>
> Love can neither be escaped or faked .

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sentence:

> There is neither an escape from this prison nor a path to wardenhood.

We would typically repeat an article (an escape...a path) if there is one in the first element, but not, if not:

> There is neither escape from this prison nor path to wardenhood.

A stylistic pressure, not a grammatical rule.

Comment: I d like to say there is no escape from love and also there is no faking love. how could you merge these in simplest and grammatically correct way?

Comment: There's no faking or escape from love.